# Variable length error in R ANOVA loop

Tags: r, lm, anova

I am currently trying to run an ANOVA on my dataframe, which has a format as such:

```
ethnicity sampleID batch gender gene1 gene2 gene3 ...
```

..up to a couple of thousand genes, with the table filled out by gene expression values.

Below is the code I am using to try and run an anova for each gene to find differences between ethnicity:

```
# here, 'merge' is the dataframe as described above
# set ethnicity to categorical
merge$ethnicity <- factor(merge$ethnicity, levels=c("Chinese","Malay","Indian"))

# parametric anova for each gene
baseformula <- " ~ ethnicity"
for (i in 5:ncol(merge))
{
  p <- anova(lm(colnames(merge)[i] ~ ethnicity, data=merge))  # variable lengths differ??
}
```

When I try running this code, I am getting the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = colnames(merge)[i] ~ ethnicity,
>   :    variable lengths differ (found for 'ethnicity')

I have checked the lengths of my ethnicity column, which is the same as the lengths of my gene1 column. I have also attempted to use the `na.omit()` command for `merge$ethnicity` but it still gives the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem is?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Here are the first five lines for my dataframe:

Here are the first five rows and first five columns for my dataframe:

```
    ethnicity sample.id Batch Gender X7896759  
1           1 H60903    B6      1  6.19649  
2           1 H61603    B2      1  6.74464  
3           1 H61608    B7      2  6.20268  
4           1 H62204    B4      1  6.71395  
5           1 H62901    B7      2  6.59963
```

Using the code:

```
for (i in 5:ncol(merge))
{
  print(colnames(merge)[i])
  print(summary(aov(merge[,i] ~ merge$ethnicity)))

}
```

appears to be giving me the following error:

> Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
>   In addition: Warning messages: 1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
>   using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored 2: In
>   Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Note that 'merge' is the name of a function in R; so it is advised to not name your object as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated an example. `df` contains a variable `etnicity`, with has 3 groups, and there are two genes. `etnicity` is your predictor variable. The `loop` prints the `aov` summary result for every gene in association to `etnicity`.

```
set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(etnicity=c('A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C'), gene1=rnorm(9), gene2=rnorm(9))

for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
  print(colnames(df)[i])
  print( summary( aov(df[,i] ~ df$etnicity) ) )
  }

[1] "gene1"
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
df$etnicity  2  1.324  0.6619   1.006   0.42
Residuals    6  3.947  0.6579               
[1] "gene2"
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
df$etnicity  2  2.436   1.218   0.977  0.429
Residuals    6  7.478   1.246
```

Applied it to data mare similar to the OP's.

```
df <- read.table(text="ethnicity sample.id Batch Gender X7896759  
1           1 H60903    B6      1  6.19649  
2           1 H61603    B2      1  6.74464  
3           2 H61608    B7      2  6.20268  
4           2 H62204    B4      1  6.71395  
5           3 H62901    B7      2  6.59963", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)  


for(i in 5:ncol(df)){
  print(colnames(df)[i])
  print(summary(aov(df[,i]~df$ethnicity)))
}

[1] "X7896759"
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
df$ethnicity  1 0.00803 0.00803   0.084  0.791
Residuals     3 0.28767 0.09589
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! I had a go at adapting your code, but I am getting the following error:  


`Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`  



I have tried converting my ethnicity levels to numeric, but it is still giving the error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not really. You could (1) setup your data as my df example or (2) provide us a small representative example of your data so that we can see the data structure.

Comment: Alright, I have added the first five rows and first five columns to my dataframe as an edit to my post. Sorry, I am not sure how to format it for a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, it seems like it works when I write it out to a table, and then read it in again. There may be something wrong with how I built the dataframe, I shall go and look into that. Thanks very much nonetheless!